# Comparing the contents of strings regardless of its order

Tags: c++, googlemock

Is there a way to compare two strings' contents not taking into account their order? i.e `edcc` and `cdce` are true since the frequency of each letter and the letter itself match

For instance, the following should be true.

```
std::string s1 = "Hello World";
std::string s2 = "World Hello";
```

The following seems equivalent to `EXPECT_EQ(s1, s2)` but is there any way to verify just the contents?

```
EXPECT_THAT(s1, ContainerEq(s2));
```

The following won't work as it seems to only work with containers like vector, arrays...

```
EXPECT_THAT(s1, UnorderedElementsAre(s2));
```

I have also tried the following void attempt

```
std::vector<char> vec1(s1.begin(), s1.end());
std::vector<char> vec2(s2.begin(), s2.end());

EXPECT_THAT(vec1, UnorderedElementsAreArray(vec2));
```

Comment: Please define what, exactly, "order" means to you. Would the following two strings: "abc" and "cba" be considered the same "order"? After all, both strings contain the same set of letters, just like "Hello World" and "World Hello".

Comment: You're right. Same number of letters i.e `de` == `ed`

Comment: @xyf Use `std::set` or `std::multiset`. For example `std::set<char>(s1.begin(), s1.end()) == std::set<char>(s2.begin(), s2.end())`

Comment: Or you could sort the strings before comparing them.

Comment: Yeah so seemingly google mock doesn't offer any library to get around it

Comment: Sorting a copy of a string will usually be preferable to creating a `multiset`. A `multiset` will normally allocate nodes individually, and each node will contain one data item plus (at least) two pointers. So in a `set<char>`, each byte of actual data will also store 16 bytes of pointers, and often some balancing information as well (and then that size will be rounded up to the next larger size the allocator supports--often a power of 2, so each byte of actual data will occupy 32 bytes of storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to copy things into `std::vector`, `std::string` is also an accepted container to `UnorderedElementsAreArray`:

```
EXPECT_THAT(s1, ::testing::UnorderedElementsAreArray(s2));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E9zKs4fxx

Getting it to ignore case would be a bit more involved, as it would require some custom matcher probably (ready matcher ignoring case only matches whole string).

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use  `std::multiset` or `std::set`:

```
if(std::multiset<char>(s1.begin(), s1.end()) == std::multiset<char>(s2.begin(), s2.end()))
{
    std::cout << "same";
}
else 
{
    std::cout<<"not same";
}
```

Comment: Why multiset over just set?

Comment: @xyf `std::set` would not account for duplicated characters.  (In your example, exactly two `c`s)

Comment: Fair. How'd you fare against std::sort?